# Is there a way to force SymSpell Python to return more than one correction recommendation?

Tags: python, nlp

I'm using the [symspellpy](https://symspellpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module in Python for query correction. It is really useful and fast, but I'm having a issue with it.

Is there a way to force Symspell to return more than one recommendation for correction. I need it to analyse a better correction based on my application.

I'm calling Symspell like this:

```py
suggestions = sym_spell.lookup(query, VERBOSITY_ALL, max_edit_distance=3)
```

Example of what I'm trying to do:

`query = "resende"`. The return that I want `["resende", "rezende"]`. What the method returns `["resende"]`. Note that both "resende" and "rezende" are in my dictionary.

Comment: You can try not setting `max_edit_distance=`, which defaults it [to the highest possible value](https://symspellpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/symspellpy.html#symspellpy.symspellpy.SymSpell.lookup): `suggestions = sym_spell.lookup(query, VERBOSITY_ALL)` . You could also change the dictionary to one with more words, I would try checking that your dictionary is actually able to suggest the suggestion you want.

Comment: @Boris thank you for your time in correcting my question and answering it. I removed the `max_edit_distance=` setting, but it didn't work as expected.

However, I think I realised something. I actually want to correct a word that is inside my dict. I'll rewrite my question so this point is more clear.

Comment: Did you try increasing `max_dictionary_edit_distance` when loading the dictionary?

Comment: I was before, but I already corrected that.

Comment: So if you set like `max_dictionary_edit_distance=100` and then don't pass in `max_edit_distance` at all, you still get one result?

Comment: running with `sym_spell._max_dictionary_edit_distance = 100` it still just return one of the results. I made two tests, the first the way you asked and the second with `max_edit_distance=100` , but it also doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post your full code and tell me where the dictionary is from so that I can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @Boris I've figured out what was going on. I passed the variable **VERBOSITY_ALL** as parameter, but it contains just the integer 2. The correct way is passing `Verbosity.ALL` from `from symspellpy import Verbosity`

Comment: You can answer your own question, that way if anyone ever makes the same mistake in the future they might see your solution right away

Answer (score 1):

Merely a typo. Change the underscore in

`Verbosity_ALL` ... to

`Verbosity.ALL`

*The three options are `CLOSEST`, `TOP` and `ALL`*

Couple of other things in SymSpell ...

### Four algorithm choices

*Described [here](https://githubhot.com/repo/mammothb/symspellpy/issues/70?page=2)*

Supported edit distance algorithm choices.

```
LEVENSHTEIN      = 0        Levenshtein algorithm
DAMERAU_OSA      = 1        Damerau optimal string alignment algorithm  (default)
LEVENSHTEIN_FAST = 2        Fast Levenshtein algorithm
DAMERAU_OSA_FAST = 3        Fast Damerau optimal string alignment algorithm

DAMERAU_OSA    # high count/frequency wins when using .ALL but distances tied?
LEVENSHTEIN    # lowest edit distance wins (fewest changes needed)
```

To change from the default, overwrite it with one of them:

```
from symspellpy.editdistance import DistanceAlgorithm
sym_spell._distance_algorithm = DistanceAlgorithm.LEVENSHTEIN
```

### Output object details

```
word = 'something'
matches = sym_spell.lookup(word, Verbosity.ALL, max_edit_distance=2)
for match in matches:   # match is ... term, distance, count
    print(f'{word} -> {match.term}   {match.distance}   {match.count}')
```

### Using collections Counter() with SymSpell instead of loading words from file

SymSpell can only read the dictionary of ok words from a file currently (Apr 2022) however this can be added inside symspellpy.py to make it able to read from a collections Counter() output dict or other dictionary of `words : counts`, a mere quick hack that works for my purposes ...

```
def load_Counter_dictionary(self, counts_each):
    for key, count in counts_each.items():
        self.create_dictionary_entry(key, count)
```

Can then drop the use of load_dictionary(), for something like this instead ...

```
sym_spell.load_Counter_dictionary( Counter(words_list) )
```

*The reason I resorted to that is a million+ record csv file was already loaded into a pandas dataframe containing a column of codes (think words) with some of them in large numbers (likely correct) along with outliers to be corrected and a column already made containing their counts each. So rather than saving the counts dict to file (expensive) and the reload by SymSpell, this is direct and efficient.*